# Django - converting URL into links, images, objects

Tags: python, django, parsing, filter

I'm creating simple comment-like application and need to convert normal urls into links, image links into images and yt/vimeo/etc. links into flash objects. E.g.:

```
http://foo.bar to <a href="http://foo.bar">http://foo.bar</a>
http://foo.bar/image.gif to <img src="http://foo.bar/image.gif"/>
etc.
```

Of course i can write all of that by myself, but i think it's such obvious piece of code that somebody has already wrote it (maybe even with splitting text into

paragraphs). I was googling for some time but couldn't find anything complex, just few snippets. Does filter (or something like that) exist?

Thanks!

PS. There is urlize but it works only for the first case.

Answer (score 4):

Write a [custom filter](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) to handle all the necessary cases. Look at the [source code for urlize](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/template/defaultfilters.py#L311) to get started. You'll also need the [urlize function](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/html.py#L77) from utils.

In your filter, first test for the first case and call urlize on that.  Handle the second case and any other cases you may have.

Comment: Like I said: I can write everything by myself but it costs time and i can't guarantee that it would work perfectly. I think these cases are so common that appropriate filter is ready and well tested.

Comment: Well, nothing is *guaranteed* to work perfectly.  If you really need to make sure all edge cases are handled correctly write some unit tests for the filter. That someone wrote it and put it on the internet does not make it infallible.  Furthermore, at some point it is quicker and better to just write your own, especially when it is something as simple as this.